# Merge results from two different tables with different column number, ORDER them by same key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
Table A: ID Cars Planes Num
          1    3      5   2
          2    8      44  1
          3    7      23  6
          4    6      2   7

Table B: ID Horses Dogs Cats Elefants Num
          1    3      5   2      3     3  
          2    8      44  1     22     4
          3    7      23  4     14     8
          4    6      2   3     15     5
```

What I need to do: I need to get all results from both tables and sort them by the "Num" Column, where the "number" actually is unique for each result from both rows.

Is it even possible to "merge" those two tables and order them by "num" or should I just get each table separately ordered and do two loops checking always for the next num jumping between tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can merge them like that with UNION .

try this:

```
select num from(
    select num from table1
    union all
    select num from table2
    )t
order by num asc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72ba88/4)

EDIT:

```
select id ,Cars,Planes, Horses,Dogs,Cats,Elefants,num from(
    select id ,Cars,Planes,'No horses' Horses,'No dogs' Dogs,'No cats' Cats,'No elefants' Elefants,num from table1
union all
select id,'No cars' Cars,'No planes' Planes,Horses,dogs,Cats,Elefants, num from table2
 )t
 order by num asc;
```

[**DEmo with other columns**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b852/2)

Comment: thanks very much, but I dont need just the num column, i also need to keep all other columns. Thanks

Comment: this just example  :) , you can add other columns :) wil ledit

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72ba88/8 take a look, it gives an error if i want to select all columns.

Comment: No your fiddle is wrong because the tables have different number of columns, look my edit fiddle , you can add the other missed columns i just put some.

Comment: thanks very much, is it somehow possible to do this without defining the exact columns i want? so only with usage of "select *" ?

Comment: No you cant do select * , because they have diffenrent columns number. You must select columns. look edited answer , i have added all columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NUM FROM TABLEA
UNION ALL
SELECT NUM FROM TABLEB
ORDER BY 1
```